# Microsoft Graph API One Drive Unable to read JSON request payload

Tags: onedrive, microsoft-graph-api

I receive the following error when I make an PUT API CALL to upload a document to OneDrive using Microsoft Graph API. It was working earlier, it has stopped working suddenly.

> {\r\n  \"error\": {\r\n    \"code\": \"BadRequest\",\r\n
>   \"message\": \"Unable to read JSON request payload. Please ensure
>   Content-Type header is set and payload is of valid JSON format.\",\r\n
>   \"innerError\": {\r\n      \"request-id\":
>   \"133ac360-740d-4823-9a93-1090616d925b\",\r\n      \"date\":
>   \"2016-04-11T06:24:59\"\r\n    }\r\n  }\r\n}

The code which I am executing is

```
 using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                string url = https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/Test.xslx:/content
                using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Put, url))
                {
                    string headerAcceptTest = "application/json";
                    MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue headerAccept = new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(headerAcceptTest);
                    request.Headers.Accept.Add(headerAccept);
                    request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
                    request.Content = new ByteArrayContent(data);
                    request.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");

                    using (var response = await client.SendAsync(request))
                    {
                        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Created)
                        {
                            string responseContentAsString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Any clue where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was an issue with a new build that was rolled out over the weekend, and we have now reverted it. The issue should now be resolved.

Comment: Sriram,

How can we expect to be made aware of such changes in the future?  There was nothing in the change log, or the Graph API documentation web site. We had a similar failing in the API a couple of weeks ago where parentheses in uploaded file names stopped working (presumably due to a new build being rolled out and breaking this functionality). This API is being used in mission critical apps and these kinds of things are really problematic.

Comment: Thanks Sriram, that is a relief. It would be great if Microsoft can provide a Service Status or a more frequently updated change log. It would be very helpful.

Comment: The current thinking is to have API changes and new features included in change log. Since this is an already supported API, I doubt it would have made the change log. But the feedback around having service status page is noted. In this case, there was a gap in our validation gates and monitoring for this particular operation that did not stop the faulty build roll out. We are working on addressing these gaps right away. @Camden, can you share any detail on have on the issue you mentioned that happened couple of weeks ago? We want to make sure it is addressed as well.

Comment: @SriramDhanasekaran-MSFT Uploading a document with the filename containing opening or closing parentheses fails using the following API call:
- https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/item_uploadcontent
This was working when we originally developed our solution, but randomly stopped working. We had to immediately change our code to disallow parentheses in file names, and change our naming convention for duplicate file names (which used parentheses before).

Answer (score 3):

I saw a change in behavior of the One Drive API on uploading a file to One Drive.( https://dev.onedrive.com/items/upload_put.htm) , this API call fails with error.

Sample Request :

PUT https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/root/children/732f64cc-0719-4a24-abe8-6fd39cb96403.txt/content?%40name.conflictBehavior=replace

Response

{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Unable to read JSON request payload. Please ensure Content-Type header is set and payload is of valid JSON format.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "7e734f93-3033-4bb4-a433-c5d9c400f46e",
            "date": "2016-04-11T02:33:35"
        }
    }
}

Actually it was working fine until 8th April 2016, The Documentation says its text/plain content type , why is this expecting application/json

Comment: So, we are not the only one. Our app was using the group variation of uploading item. Please reply if you get to solve this in future.

Comment: We are also experiencing this problem.